# Programmer's Problem

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

A quick Google search tells that the meaning of *in* is:

> expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else.

and the meaning of *into* is:

> expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something becomes enclosed or surrounded by something else.

But in my line of work people usually seem to use these words as they are interchangeable when they talk of `values` and `registers`.
I wonder which one of these sentence would be grammatically correct.

> Put the value **in** register A and start executing the program.
>   Put the value **into** register A and start executing the program.

Furthermore, how this usage would change if the word `Put` is replaced with `Load`. Would it be `in`, `into`, `on` or `onto`?

PS : For those who know English but not computers, a `Register` is simply a location in computer's memory to hold a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are "moving" a value from being not in the register to being there, use *into* because it indicates such movement or action.

> Put the value **into** register A and start executing the program.

Using *Load* would be the same since it refers to the same action.

> Load the value **into** register A and start executing the program.

After that:

> The value of 2 is **in** the register.

or

> The value **in** register A is then moved to register B.

because it is contained there, and there is no action.

However, in informal use either one is commonly used. The context is clear regardless.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, both are understandable and used

> Put the value 5 **in** register A
>   Put the value 5 **into** register A

but when referring to what register A is holding

> The value 5 is **in** register A